# How to get previous row value in HTML grid using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to get previous column value in grid using Javascript/JQuery.

The Field A,B and C always input field(Textbox) values. In first row the D,E,F values always will be "NA" and in second row onwards the value of D,E,F should be previous row value of A,B,C as per given below. How to get previous columns value using jQuery.

```
A   B   C  D  E  F  
--------------------
10  20  30 NA NA NA Edit
40  50  70 10 20 30 Edit
66  27  38 40 50 70 Edit
```

As per my below code, I am getting previous row result. But suppose when I click on Edit on second row , then it is reading current column values from A,B,C. It should read previous column values of A,B,C.
I have HTML fields to make the grid.

```html
var xyz=0
 $("tbody").find("tr").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).find('td.tdColumnofAText').text();

        if ($(this).find('td.tdColumnofAText').text() > 0) {
                xyz = Number(val);

        }

    });

    $('#txtofDValue').val(xyz);
```

Comment: See [jQuery documentation: Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) for moving around in the DOM.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `.each()` accepts two parameters, `index` and `element`. You can use these to select the previous Row.

Comment: *It should read previous column values* - do you mean it should read previous *row* values?  So if you click edit on row 3, you edit row 2 values?

Comment: Yes. When i click on Edit on row 3 to change A,B,C values from current row 3 values, that time internally it should read row 2 values from A,B,C column(as per above example 40,50,70) and get those values into current row D,E, F column values as 40,50,70 respectively . As per my code, it is not able to read previous row values whiling editing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function initTable(table) {
    var cur;
    var next;
    $("tbody tr", table).each(function(index, elem) {
      cur = [
        $("td:eq(0)", this).text().trim(),
        $("td:eq(1)", this).text().trim(),
        $("td:eq(2)", this).text().trim()
      ];
      next = $(this).next();
      if (next !== undefined) {
        $("td:eq(3)", next).html(cur[0]);
        $("td:eq(4)", next).html(cur[1]);
        $("td:eq(5)", next).html(cur[2]);
      }

    });
  }

  initTable($("table"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>70</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

This loops through each row and collects some values. It then adds it to specific cells in the Next row, if it exists.